# There was problem loading requested app.it looks like you may be using LAN URL

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am not able to compile my project through expo.I have followed all steps to eject expo for run the app in iOS.Please find below error screen shot for your reference.[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zLK.png)
[image]

Comment: Did you run the app through xcode?

Comment: @hongdevelop - Yes I tried in both way but no use.

Comment: Did you try this? expo init your project => expo start --ios => click ios simulator

Comment: @hongdevelop - I have tried same then it will create new project then lt will show blank screen.any let me re cross verify your steps will update you after some time.Thanks for your response.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @klippy :- no its not resolved.

Comment: I just change the Connection to Tunnel and scan the QR Code (using IOS) and it works for me.

Answer (score 21):

## Try `expo-cli start --tunnel` Working for me.

```
 [16:13:53] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002 
 [16:14:10] Your native app is running at exp://fa-2jw.testdev.testdev-expo.exp.direct:80
```

Answer (score 7):

If the new project build doesn't solve it,

Your uri will look like this.

```
Your URL is: exp://192.168.43.61:19000
```

as opposed to this.

```
exp://9h-hcy.bacon.tickle_me_elmo.exp.direct:80
```

Then you can try this.

`exp start --tunnel` and check to make sure you have a pretty solid wifi connection

**If not** `exp start -m tunnel`

A [detailed description](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/) of the connection.

Comment: Tried above steps but not simulating properly.Can you check?

Comment: Yes..don't know whats problem.. :(

Comment: expo start --tunnel worked for me in 2023

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and no answer here helped me. In fact, I've had a older version of Expo on my iPhone. So, I've update to the latest expo version in my iPhone and then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I updated both Node.js on the computer and Expo App on mobile to the latest version. then it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was that my computer was connected to another Wifi than my iPhone.

So to make this work, both devices have to be in the same network.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

OHH! I had a projected downloaded from google drive, and the project had its own projectId, so it took 2 hours to sort it!

remove this below from your app.json, your run becomes normal.

```
"extra": {
  "eas": {
    "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Every few months, I get caught out by this error!

If you are using `eas` for building expo projects, you will get OPs error if the expo account you are logged in with on the expo cli isn't set up to access the eas project ID specified in your `auth.json`.

It is worth running `expo whoami` and checking which account you are signed in as. As someone who uses different accounts for different customers, it catches me out all the time!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by granting permission for expo to access my local network. 
I did this by going to settings > scroll down to expo go and select > toggle on local network.
IOS: 17.2

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. 
I am using PC, compile my project through expo and testing on Iphone. 
This worked for me.

```
yarn ios
```

When i used yarn start, I got the same error message as you.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of hours and trying various the below trick worked for me My node version was updated to 13.0. I downgraded by following below commands

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 12.14.1
```

and reinstalled expo cli again
expo version is 3.24.2. (you can check version by expo -- version)

- created new project by command expo init (projectName)
- npm start
- once metro bundler
- toggle LAN to toggle and then set back to LAN
  as shown in picture[image: toggle LAN to toggle and then set back to LAN]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you switch from the LAN toggle to the Tunnel toggle in youre browser Localhost after running expo start in terminal. also make sure your internet is stable.

Answer (score 0):

besides what others have written, also certain node versions could make this error happen. I solved it by switch node the version from 18.6.0 to 18.14.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I get rid of it by following these steps:

1. restart the server with **npm start**.
2. Connect the data cable to your android phone.
3. press **a** to open the project on your phone.

Hopefully, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

If running
`expo-cli start --tunnel` results in

ExpoMetroConfig.loadAsync is not a function ERROR

use

`npx expo start --tunnel`